# Legal to restrict tenant parking to leaseholders with valid driver license?

Tags: residential-lease, is-x-legal

So I must begin with saying that the parking at my apartment is first come first serve, free for all kind of parking (as long as you're a tenant). There is no off-site parking.

The management team decided to send out a notice today that states: due to overcrowding residents must now have a parking permit. Which I have to admit is not a bad idea, but it comes with conditions: You can only get a pass if your name is on the lease and you have a valid drivers license.  Can they legally enforce the second condition?

Comment: What country/state?

Answer (score 1):

You have to read your lease to be sure.

But in all likelihood, yes they can enforce this. This is a common situation and has become *de facto* standard operating procedure.